# How to solve .accepted_renderer not set on Response Error on POST Request, Django

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, itemrenderer

got a problem when trying to call request using Postman, on POST request always get

```
AssertionError at /v1/facility/33/court/ .accepted_renderer not set on Response Request Method: POST Request URL:
```

On Get request other endpoints works fine.
Django version - 3.2.15

Class that responsible for this endpoint already have APIView class

```
class ItemAPIView(
CSRFEnabledApiViewMixin, CreateAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
```

Even If I put *APIView* class as last nested class it not working.

Who can help with this? what is wrong?

Note: if I will doing ***curl*** request to such endpoint POST - error is the same

Answer (score 0):

accepted_renderer` is an attribute for request from DjangoRestFramework.

Django itself don't add `accepted_renderer` to request.

Try to check if you call the DRF-view with Django request.